# Как исправить ошибку iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. при билде в юнити?

Tags: ios, unity3d, xcode, cocoapods

Добавил в unity firebase оповещения. При билде вылезает такая ошибка. КАк исправить?:
iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and failed. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions

Удалил и установил cocoapods, как там сказано

Comment: Солюшен-то нашелся в результате? У меня вот такая же ситуяция.